# How to remove Phonegap Build Permission alert in iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, alert, construct

I'm using Phonegap Build to compile a game I made using Construct 2.
Now when I install the game on my iphone a geolocation permission alerts pops up, although my game doesn't use geolocation.

I think phonegap somehow inserts geolocation code into the .ipa file
I thought this wasn't gonna be a problem, but I submitted the game to the appstore and the reviewer is asking me what features of my game use geolocation. My game status in itunes connect right now is 'metadata rejected' because of this.

Is there a way to remove this geolocation thing?
I already googled the problem but I can't find a solution.

Here's my config.xml file:

```
>  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/> <preference 
> name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" /> <feature 
> name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/> <gap:config-file 
> platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden"><true/></gap:config-file> 
> <gap:config-file platform="ios" 
> parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance"><false/></gap:config-file> </widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

@gleegum, when you install the plugin via config.xml, it will initiate the Geolocation permission sequence. Did you perhaps accidentally insert the geolocation plugin into your config.xml? -Jesse

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JesseMonroy650

I didn't install any plug-in AFAIK.
Here's my config.xml file:

`code´
 <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />

 <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
 <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden"><true/></gap:config-file>
 <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance"><false/></gap:config-file>
</widget>
`code´

Comment: Yes, but that is NOT all of your config.xml file. However, I believe you did NOT insert the plugin by accident. I think you might have to ask for help from the forum for  *Construct 2*. The answer you are looking for here is: You cannot have a permission request for geolocation unless you install the plugin. --Jesse